# How to sort strings from a file by giving each line an ordered index using insertion sort in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, indexing, insertion

I'm having trouble sorting this file, giving each line an index. The whole point is to prompt the user to type in the index so the program can return the program line that corresponds to the index number.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void printUnsortedStringFromFile(int amount, char A[]);
void printSortedStringFromFile(int amount, char A[]);
//bool binSearchNUM(int amount, int A[amount], int target, int *current);

int main()
{

    FILE* spData = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    int ch, number_of_lines = 0;
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(spData);
        if (ch == '\n')
            number_of_lines++;
    } while (ch != EOF);

    if (ch != '\n' && number_of_lines != 0)
        number_of_lines++;

    fclose(spData);

    printf("There are %d lines in file grades.csv . \n", number_of_lines);
    int amount = number_of_lines;
    char A[amount];
    printUnsortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
    printSortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
    return 0;
}


void printUnsortedStringFromFile(int amount, char A[])
{
    FILE *spData;
    spData = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    if(spData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file grades.csv.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    int ex1;
    int ex2;
    int ex3;
    int StudentNUM;
    char StudentAVG;

    printf("+-------+------+------+------+-----+\n");
    printf("|Student|Exam 1|Exam 2|Exam 3|Grade|\n");
    printf("+-------+------+------+------+-----+\n");
    int z = 0;
    while((fgets(A, amount, spData)) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(A, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %c", &StudentNUM, &ex1, &ex2, &ex3, &StudentAVG);
        printf("| %d|    %d|    %d|    %d|    %c| \n", StudentNUM, ex1, ex2, ex3, StudentAVG);
        z++;
//prints unsorted correctly
    }
    printf("+-------+------+------+------+-----+\n");

    if (fclose(spData) == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing the file grades.csv. \n");
        exit(2);
    }
}
void printSortedStringFromFile(int amount, char A[])
{
    FILE *spData;
    spData = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    if(spData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file grades.csv.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
  //help needed implementing insertion sort to sort each string as an index here
    {
    int walk;
    int temp;
    for (int cur = 1; cur < amount; cur++)
        {
        bool located = false;
         temp = A[cur], walk = cur-1;
        while (walk >= 0 && !located)
        {
            if (temp < A[walk])
                {
                A[walk+1] = A[walk];
                walk--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        located = true;
                    }
        }
            A[walk+1] = temp;
        }
    }


    int StudentNUM;
    char StudentAVG;

    printf("+-----+-------+-----+\n");
    printf("|Index|Student|Grade|\n");
    printf("+-----+-------+-----+\n");
    int z = 0;
    while((fgets(A, amount, spData)) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(A, "%d, %c", &StudentNUM, &StudentAVG);
        printf("|    %d|    %c| \n", StudentNUM, StudentAVG);
        z++;
//student ID prints, grade average doesn/t, unsure how to sort these strings into a numbered(index) list
    }
    if (fclose(spData) == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing the file grades.csv. \n");
        exit(2);
    }

}
/* (correct) example output:
There are 5 lines in file grades.csv.
Original:
+-------+------+------+------+-----+
|Student|Exam 1|Exam 2|Exam 3|Grade|
+-------+------+------+------+-----+
| 535743|    67|    96|    93|    B|
| 112213|    87|    65|    72|    C|
| 612778|    59|    58|    97|    C|
| 151774|    52|   100|    86|    C|
| 406704|    54|    72|    80|    D|
+-------+------+------+------+-----+
Sorted:
+-----+-------+-----+
|Index|Student|Grade|
+-----+-------+-----+
|    1| 112213|    C|
|    2| 151774|    C|
|    3| 406704|    D|
|    4| 535743|    B|
|    5| 612778|    C|
+-----+-------+-----+
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Answer Part One.**

The main problem in your source code is the string `char A[amount];`.

In the `main()` function the variable `A` is allocated to the number of lines ?!!

> In your example, `number_of_lines = 5` means `A[amount] = A[5]` is
>   able to store only a 4-characters string + null terminator.

```
printf("There are %d lines in file grades.csv . \n", number_of_lines);
int amount = number_of_lines;
char A[amount];
printUnsortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
printSortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
```

Then on both `printUnsortedStringFromFile()` and `printSortedStringFromFile()` functions the same variable `A` is used as a buffer to load and read one line.

> In your example, the first line of 'grades.csv' is longer 4 characters
>   and is truncated before calling `sscanf()`.

```
while((fgets(A, amount, spData)) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(A, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %c", &StudentNUM, &ex1, &ex2, &ex3, &StudentAVG);
```

> A solution could be to use a local `char sTmp[80]` for the `fgets()`
>   and `sscanf()` and use the `A[amount]` only for the indexation.

---

> **Answer Part Two.**

The second problem in your source code is that the suggested indexation in order to ascending student-id sort records by insertion sort, needs to store not only the index but also the content of each record. I suggest to use define a structure as follow:

```
struct gradesRecord {
    int iIndex;       // index on the file
    int iStudentNUM;  // 'Student' field
    int iExamVAL[3];  // 'Exam 1'..'Exam 3' fields
    char cStudentAVG; // 'Grade' field
};
```

Then convert your `A[]` array from `char` to `struct gradesRecord`(in `main()`):

```
int amount = number_of_lines;
struct gradesRecord A[amount];
printUnsortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
printSortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
```

In the `printUnsortedStringFromFile()` function, the array `A[]` is used directly in the reading loop:

> To prevent a bad formatted text-file, it is recommended to check the
>   returned value of `sscanf()` in order to detect missing parameters (see the `nArg` variable and how to check bellow).

```
char sLine[81]; // local string to read one row
int z = 0; // storage index
int nArg;

while((fgets(sLine, 80, spData)) != NULL)
{
    nArg = sscanf(sLine, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %c",
        &(A[z].iStudentNUM), &(A[z].iExamVAL[0]),
        &(A[z].iExamVAL[1]), &(A[z].iExamVAL[2]),
        &(A[z].cStudentAVG));

    if (nArg != 5) {
        // the input line is not correct !!!
        // manage that error.
    }

    printf("|%7d| %5d| %5d| %5d|    %c| \n", A[z].iStudentNUM,
        A[z].iExamVAL[0], A[z].iExamVAL[1], A[z].iExamVAL[2],
        A[z].cStudentAVG);
    z++; // next row
```

Then in the `printSortedStringFromFile()` function, the array `A[]` is used to store, sort in the reading loop, then displayed in a second loop:

First loop, reading and selection sort of all rows:

```
char sLine[81];
int iLine = 0, iRow;
struct gradesRecord grRow,grTmp;

while((fgets(sLine, 80, spData)) != NULL)
{
    // extract one Row and store it into grRow
    sscanf(sLine, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %c",
        &(grRow.iStudentNUM), &(grRow.iExamVAL[0]),
        &(grRow.iExamVAL[1]), &(grRow.iExamVAL[2]),
        &(grRow.cStudentAVG));
    // keep the line index of that row
    grRow.iIndex = iLine;
    // search loop = insertion sort algorithm
    for (iRow=0;iRow<iLine;iRow++) {
        //  detect if new student is before the store one
        if (grRow.iStudentNUM < A[iRow].iStudentNUM) {
            // exchange both stuident records through grTmp
            memcpy(&grTmp,&(A[iRow]),sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
            memcpy(&(A[iRow]),&grRow,sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
            memcpy(&grRow,&grTmp,sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
        }
    }
    // store the biggest student at the end
    memcpy(&(A[iLine]),&grRow,sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
    iLine++;
}
```

Second loop, display the sorted table:

```
while (z < amount)
{
    StudentNUM = A[z].iStudentNUM;
    StudentAVG = A[z].cStudentAVG;
    index = A[z].iIndex;
    printf("| %4d|%7d|    %c| \n", index, StudentNUM, StudentAVG);
    z++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, my unsorted table is now printing out fine, but I am confused about how to sort the student ID’s in ascending order using insertion sort each with a corresponding Index.

Comment: Yes, I know that my answer is not the full solution of your question, but it is a first step to find one. Could you edit your question to highlight that **how to sort the student ID’s in ascending order using insertion sort** ?

Comment: Adding the **"Answer Part Two."** with indexation and insertion sorting.

Comment: I am having trouble with the parameters for each function, I am getting compile errors such as "array has incomplete element type" I tried putting in the "struct" but error still applys.

Comment: Did you update the prototypes from `void printUnsortedStringFromFile(int amount, char A[]);` to `void printUnsortedStringFromFile(int amount, struct gradesRecord A[]);` ?

Comment: Yes and when I call the functions  would it be     printUnsortedStringFromFile(amount, gradesRecord );
printSortedStringFromFile(amount, gradesRecord ); or gradesRecord A?

Comment: Also, should i define the variable  "nArg" as a struct because it has both char and ints?

Comment: If in `main()` your declaration is `struct gradesRecord A[amount];`, you have to call `printUnsortedStringFromFile(amount, A);` (no change from main).

Comment: Sorry for `nArg`, I have updated my answer. It is highly recommended to check the returned value from `sscanf()` call.

Comment: I am getting  
lines- 5/6/41/87- error: array type has incomplete element type, 35/36- error type of formal parameter 2 is incomplete,

Comment: @fgdark, to be sure that your are synchronizing my proposals and your source code, I have added in another Answer the full source code.

Comment: It is running now, simple mistake. I did not include <string.h>

Answer (score 0):

In order to synthesis all modifications described in the first answer, I add here the complete source as follow:

> 1- The function `main()` and `struct gradesRecord`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct gradesRecord {
    int iIndex;       // index on the file
    int iStudentNUM;  // 'Student' field
    int iExamVAL[3];  // 'Exam 1'..'Exam 3' fields
    char cStudentAVG; // 'Grade' field
};

void printUnsortedStringFromFile(int amount, struct gradesRecord A[]);
void printSortedStringFromFile(int amount, struct gradesRecord A[]);

int main()
{

    FILE* spData = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    int ch, number_of_lines = 0;
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(spData);
        if (ch == '\n')
            number_of_lines++;
    } while (ch != EOF);

    if (ch != '\n' && number_of_lines != 0)
        number_of_lines++;

    fclose(spData);

    printf("There are %d lines in file grades.csv . \n", number_of_lines);
    int amount = number_of_lines;
    struct gradesRecord A[amount];
    printUnsortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
    printSortedStringFromFile(amount, A);
    return 0;
}
```

> 2- The function `printUnsortedStringFromFile()` :

```
void printUnsortedStringFromFile(int amount, struct gradesRecord A[])
{
    FILE *spData;
    spData = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    if(spData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file grades.csv.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("+-------+------+------+------+-----+\n");
    printf("|Student|Exam 1|Exam 2|Exam 3|Grade|\n");
    printf("+-------+------+------+------+-----+\n");
    char sLine[81]; // local string to read one row
    int z = 0;
    while((fgets(sLine, 80, spData)) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(sLine, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %c",
            &(A[z].iStudentNUM), &(A[z].iExamVAL[0]),
            &(A[z].iExamVAL[1]), &(A[z].iExamVAL[2]),
            &(A[z].cStudentAVG));

        printf("|%7d| %5d| %5d| %5d|    %c| \n", A[z].iStudentNUM,
            A[z].iExamVAL[0], A[z].iExamVAL[1], A[z].iExamVAL[2],
            A[z].cStudentAVG);
        z++;
    }
    printf("+-------+------+------+------+-----+\n");

    if (fclose(spData) == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing the file grades.csv. \n");
        exit(2);
    }
}
```

> 3- And the function `printSortedStringFromFile()` :

```
void printSortedStringFromFile(int amount, struct gradesRecord A[])
{
    FILE *spData;
    spData = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    if(spData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening the file grades.csv.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char sLine[81];
    int iLine = 0, iRow;
    struct gradesRecord grRow,grTmp;

    while((fgets(sLine, 80, spData)) != NULL)
    {
        // extract one Row and store it into grRow
        sscanf(sLine, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %c",
            &(grRow.iStudentNUM), &(grRow.iExamVAL[0]),
            &(grRow.iExamVAL[1]), &(grRow.iExamVAL[2]),
            &(grRow.cStudentAVG));
        // keep the line index of that row
        grRow.iIndex = iLine;
        // search loop = insertion sort algorithm
        for (iRow=0;iRow<iLine;iRow++) {
            //  detect if new student is before the store one
            if (grRow.iStudentNUM < A[iRow].iStudentNUM) {
                // exchange both stuident records through grTmp
                memcpy(&grTmp,&(A[iRow]),sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
                memcpy(&(A[iRow]),&grRow,sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
                memcpy(&grRow,&grTmp,sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
            }
        }
        // store the biggest student at the end
        memcpy(&(A[iLine]),&grRow,sizeof(struct gradesRecord));
        iLine++;
    }

    int StudentNUM;
    char StudentAVG;

    printf("+-----+-------+-----+\n");
    printf("|Index|Student|Grade|\n");
    printf("+-----+-------+-----+\n");
    int z = 0;
    int index;
    while (z < amount)
    {
        StudentNUM = A[z].iStudentNUM; // access to sorted array
        StudentAVG = A[z].cStudentAVG;
        index = A[z].iIndex;
        printf("| %4d|%7d|    %c| \n", index, StudentNUM, StudentAVG);
        z++;
    }
    if (fclose(spData) == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing the file grades.csv. \n");
        exit(2);
    }

}
```